# How to select value in a table based on date range that may change

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to find a question that specifically addresses the requirements of what I'm trying to do here, but apologies if this isn't the case.

I have an example table:

```
    type|start_date|end_date  |cost|

    bananas|2019-01-01|2019-01-31|100
    bananas|2019-02-01|2019-02-28|95
    juice  |null      |null      |55
```

And so on. The point of the table is that the 'food' or whatever else, can be a different price based on a different time range, however there are some items e.g. juice, that don't get affected when the date changes (i.e they stay constant).

In another table, I want to lookup a value based on the date range in the table above.

For example:

```
customerId|transaction_date|item   |quantity|

abc123    |2019-01-25      |bananas|4
abc126    |2019-02-06      |bananas|4
abc128    |2019-02-09      |juice  |1
```

So the first two customers bought bananas, but one in January and one in February.
Then another customer bought juice.
How can I return the correct corresponding cost based on my other table.

I have tried to do where date is `BETWEEN` the two, but this alienates any other dates that don't exist in the pricing table.
I've also tried to use `CASE` to approach this, but to no avail.

What would be the best approach to this?

I would expect the result to yield a joined table with the following:

```
customerId|transaction_date|item   |quantity|cost|

abc123    |2019-01-25      |bananas|4       |100
abc126    |2019-02-06      |bananas|4       |95
abc128    |2019-02-09      |juice  |1       |55
```

Where `cost` column is joined by the criteria above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ISNULL on the left join.

```
SELECT P.*, C.cost
FROM Purchases P 
LEFT JOIN Product_Costs C ON P.item = C.type 
      AND P.transaction_date >= ISNULL(C.start_date, P.transaction_date) 
      AND P.transaction_date <= ISNULL(C.end_date, P.transaction_date);
```

Modified Nick's fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e366b/6

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (select t1.cost
        from table1 t1
        where t1.type = t2.type and
              t2.transaction_date >= t1.start_date and
              t2.transaction_date <= t1.end_date 
       ) as cost
from table2 t2;
```

Or, you can use a `left join`:

```
select t2.*, t1.cost
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.type = t2.type and
        t2.transaction_date >= t1.start_date and
        t2.transaction_date <= t1.end_date ;
```

EDIT:

You can handle `NULL` values with `OR`:

```
select t2.*, t1.cost
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.type = t2.type and
        (t2.transaction_date >= t1.start_date or
         t1.start_date is null
        ) and
        (t2.transaction_date <= t1.end_date or
         t1.end_date is null
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an outer apply:

```
  SELECT p.*,
  c.cost
  FROM Purchases AS p
      OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 c.cost
              FROM Product_Costs AS c
              WHERE p.transaction_date BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date
                  AND c.type = p.Item
      ) AS c;
```

I've created a Sql Fiddle using your example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e366b/2/0